# This javascript setTimeout interacts with ajax requests in a really weird way

Tags: javascript, ajax, settimeout

I'm writing this script so that it displays the status of an import script. It's supposed to call a function, that runs a http request, every X seconds.

```
function progres_import() {
//if(import_status != 'finalizat') {
    alert("progres_import");
    setTimeout(function() { return update_progres_import(); }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() { return update_progres_import(); }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function() { return update_progres_import(); }, 6000);
    setTimeout(function() { return update_progres_import(); }, 8000);

    //setTimeout(function() { progres_import(); }, 400);
//}
//else {

//}
}
```

this is what i used to test the functionality. I put the comments in too just to show what I intend to ultimately do with it. I tried all the possible setTimeout calls, with quotes, without quotes, with and without the anonymous function.

```
var xmlhttp_import_progres;
function update_progres_import() {
xmlhttp_import_progres=GetXMLHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp_import_progres==null) {
    alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request (xmlhttp_import_progres)");
    return;
}

var url="crm/ferestre/import_progres.php";  
url=url+"?sid="+Math.random();

xmlhttp_import_progres.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp_import_progres.readyState == 4) {
        progres_resp = xmlhttp_import_progres.responseText;
        progres = progres_resp.split('_');
        import_nrc = progres[0];
        import_nrt = progres[1];
        import_status = progres[2];
        mesaj = 'Progres import: ' + import_nrc + ' / ' + import_nrt;
        //document.getElementById("corp_import_mesaj").innerHTML = mesaj;
        alert(progres_resp);        
    }
};
xmlhttp_import_progres.open("POST",url,true);
xmlhttp_import_progres.send(null);
}
```

this is the business end of the progres_import function.

what happens is i get the alert("progress_import") in the first function right as the import process starts, but the alert(progres_resp) in the second one starts popping up only after the import process is over (it still maintains the 2 second interval so in that sense the setTimeouts worked).

the php script in the ajax request just takes some session variables that the import script sets and prints them for the javascript to use (x imports of y total, z failed, stuff like this)

Any idea why it behaves like this?

Comment: Can you show fully the function: `update_progres_import`?

Comment: My first thought is that, server side, the php scripts can't be run at the same time, and If that's the case then we're screwed.

Comment: Can you show the variable `xmlhttp_import_progres` too?

Comment: I could guess what is your problem. But you need to show more details.

Comment: @vietean just pasted the whole function.

Comment: Ok, better. Please wait for me several minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xmlhttp_import_progres.readyState == 4)` is only `true` at the end of the request. Hence, your alert dialogs pop up after finishing the request.

Furthermore, you can't expect your function to show alerts after a 2 second interval, because the server may or may not respond as fast.

A final note: If you want to have a periodical update function, use `setInterval(function(){...}, 2000)`.

### EDIT

Also, add `var` in this way: `var xmlhttp_import_progres = GetXMLHttpObject();`. Currently, you're globally defining the HTTP object, causing only one instance of the HTTP object to be accessible.

Comment: I understand that the server may not respond fast enough but that's why I gave it a whole 2 seconds for what is basically a one line echo.

Comment: Yes, but consider this (server lag): *request A*, *2 seconds*, *request B*, *response A*, *response B* *2 seconds*...

Comment: i guess the question to ask is "can the server run the php script in the ajax request WHILE it's doing the import?" (the import is also a php script)

Comment: You can't directly define variables from PHP in JS. You'd better display a notification prior sending a request (`"Sending..."`), and show the results when the request has finished.

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and mark your answer but my problem still stands: It seems the import script is stopping the import_progress script from running. That's why it only starts displaying the alerts at the very end. I'm not well versed enough in the server side of things so I don't even know if you CAN run two scripts at the same time. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here, can you try to edit just a little:
**Please consider the above answer, but this code will make clear for you:**

---

```
function progres_import() {
//if(import_status != 'finalizat') {
    alert("progres_import");
    setTimeout(function() { return update_progres_import(0); }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() { return update_progres_import(1); }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function() { return update_progres_import(2); }, 6000);
    setTimeout(function() { return update_progres_import(3); }, 8000);

    //setTimeout(function() { progres_import(); }, 400);
//}
//else {

//}
}
```

AND

```
var xmlhttp_import_progres = [];
function update_progres_import(i) {
    xmlhttp_import_progres[i]= GetXMLHttpObject();
    if (xmlhttp_import_progres[i]==null) {
        alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request (xmlhttp_import_progres)");
        return;
    }

    var url="crm/ferestre/import_progres.php";  
    url=url+"?sid="+Math.random();

    xmlhttp_import_progres[i].onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp_import_progres[i].readyState == 4) {
            progres_resp = xmlhttp_import_progres[i].responseText;
            progres = progres_resp.split('_');
            import_nrc = progres[0];
            import_nrt = progres[1];
            import_status = progres[2];
            mesaj = 'Progres import: ' + import_nrc + ' / ' + import_nrt;
            //document.getElementById("corp_import_mesaj").innerHTML = mesaj;
            alert(progres_resp);        
        }
    };
    xmlhttp_import_progres[i].open("POST",url,true);
    xmlhttp_import_progres[i].send(null);
}
```